# What does "Packages cannot be nested" in AS3 mean?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, nested, package

I got the complie error "Packages cannot be nested". What does it mean, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

While you can have more than one `Class`, you should only have a single `Package` in each of your `.as` files. Check your `.as` files to see if you have more than one instance of `Package`.

---

Update based on OP's comments:

You cannot use `Packages` or `Classes` on the timeline. You need to place that code in an external file and link to it either by making it your Document Class or by assigning it to a symbol in your library via the `Class` property in the properties panel.

Comment: There was only one. I added the script directly to the file instead of importing/including.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "added the script directly to the file"? Do you mean that you copied/pasted code? If so, it's possible that the file you created (depending on the IDE you're using) automatically created a package for you and when you pasted the code you added a second package.

Comment: Yes, I copy pasted the code into the fla file. So now the code is in frame 1 of the mainscreen.